# php calling bash script with ssh

Tags: php, linux, bash

Trying to execute a bash script (with ssh command inside) from php but not working as the way it was executed on CLI.

Here is the snippet of the bash script (`deploy_to_nagios.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash -x
SERVER=$1
CARRIER=$2
MANAGEMENT_NAGIOS_SERVER=$3
MANAGEMENT_NAGIOS_USER=$4

ssh -q ${MANAGEMENT_NAGIOS_USER}@${MANAGEMENT_NAGIOS_SERVER} "ls /usr/local/nagios/health_check_${CARRIER}.cfg"
```

Running deploy_to_nagios.sh in CLI returns successfully, but when executing on php using

```
$exec3 = shell_exec('deploy_to_nagios.sh '.' '.$server.' '.$carrier.' '.$nag_manage_server.' '.$nag_manage_user);
```

the file can't be found. My guess is that php is running the ssh and the ls commands in separate that is why the file can't be found.
is there a way for the php execution behaves the same as on the CLI, treating those 2 commands as one?

Comment: Clarify: deploy_to_nagios.sh or /usr/local/nagios/health_check_${CARRIER}.cfg can not be found?

Comment: Not sure which file you're talking about that cannot be found, but if you're worried about that, then why not just use the full path of the file?

Comment: the "/usr/local/nagios/health_check_${CARRIER}.cfg" can't be found when executing deploy_to_nagios.sh via php. But that file can be found when executing the deploy_to_nagios.sh via CLI. My guess it that php is executing the "ls /usr/local/nagios/health_check_${CARRIER}.cfg" as separate command command from ssh -q ${MANAGEMENT_NAGIOS_SERVER${MANAGEMENT_NAGIOS_USER} so it possibly looking it on the local server instead on the ${MANAGEMENT_NAGIOS_USER} ?

Answer (score 0):

This project will allow PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell through ssh. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

Then either trigger your bash script or execute the command directly. Directly lets you handle the return rather than building exception logic in bash.

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
//get a remote bash shell on server: MANAGEMENT_NAGIOS_SERVER
$shell = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getRemoteHost(MANAGEMENT_NAGIOS_SERVER)->getShellBySsh(MANAGEMENT_NAGIOS_USER, 'secretPassword');

//execute the ls command (--color=none to avoid special chars from terminal colors)
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('ls --color=none /usr/local/nagios/health_check_${CARRIER}.cfg');

echo $return1; //ls return
```